# Are there source files, or only class files, in EAR projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Suppose I have an EJB project called X and a JSP project called Y. Consequently I have X.jar and Y.war . I create an EAR project called Z, adding X and Y as dependencies.

1. Will/should the source files for projects X and Y be stored in Z's project directory?
2. What exactly will project Z store about X and Y besides references to them in application.xml ?

Edit: These projects are in Eclipse.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify in which IDE these projects exist.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity, these projects are in Eclipse.

Comment: I would also be interested in common practices wherever such a pattern exists, even for other IDEs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An EAR project is mostly a wrapper project containing packaging and application server configurations.

To answer you questions.

1. No. It should not contain the source files from EJB and WAR projects
2. It will contain packaging info such as application.xml or application server specific such as jboss-deployment-strucuture.xml or project build.xml or pom.xml etc.

Comment: @PercyLynn You will steer clear of any IDE dependencies if you use build tools like maven